# Measure of goodness of 2D data points for classification

Tags: numpy, math, machine-learning, statistics, classification

Is there a good measure of how good my dataset is for the task of classification. The ideal scenario for classification is that points for each class should be clustered closer and each cluster of different classes should be far apart. Is there a way to measure this goodness.
A Good dataset would look like this
[image: A Good dataset]
And a bad dataset would look like this
[image]

**Background**:
I am trying to classify a few images from their 2048 dimensional embeddings generated by inception-v3 model. I tried visualizing the model by doing dimentionality reduction to 3 dimensions but it loses a lot of information. I am trying to figure out if the embeddings of my images with same class cluster together and different clusters are far apart.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't any conclusive answer, but people try things like k nearest neighbors with a small number of neighbors, e.g. k = 3 to 10 or something like that. k-NN with small k gives a lower bound (i.e. optimistic) on classification error. So that can give you sense of what's the best you can hope for. Hope that helps, btw this question is really more suitable for stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks @RobertDodier. I want to do this analysis before I start doing classification. I just want to judge my embedding generation process. I will try asking this in stats. :)

Comment: Right -- this is something people do before they get underway with their method of choice. In your case, this will give an indication of how useful are the dimensions you've chosen. Good luck and have fun.